# Mathematical approch to measuring current, voltage and resistance of mixed series and parallel

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, parallel, series

If there is a circuit like the one below, where all resistors are 1k ohm, how does one determine the currents? The voltage sources are all 10 volts.

The problem I am having is that I do not know if the top voltage source takes the zero resistance path in the middle or if the bottom one does.

NOTE: This is not a homework question.

[image: A circuit with mixed voltages. How to dertermine current?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is one important low-impedance node in the whole circuit. That's the frame and the cross in the middle. Let's call that 0v. The top voltage source is connected to the middle via that 1k resistor, that means the lower voltage source has priority.

The current flowing in:

- the bottom resistor must therefore be 10v/1k = 10mA.
- the right resistor must be 0mA, because it has the same voltage on both sides.
- the two resistors in the top half form a potential divider between 0v and 0v, so you might think of the top voltage source as sitting at about 0v too. However, since it's generating a voltage, then the top side will be at 5v, and the bottom side at -5v.

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Rather than hand-waving your last point, you should just state that V2 drives 5mA through R1 and R3, and this current establishes the voltages on either side of V2 relative to the reference node.

Answer (score 6):

First, let's redraw your circuit in a way that might be a little more clear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI45xZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ammeter AM1 is measuring the current you are asking about.

The way you would analyze this circuit by superposition, or by mesh analysis, both currents use that path. And the final current is the sum of the currents produced by the two voltage sources V1 and V2.

Comment: You could have simplified further by replacing R2 and R3 by a single 2k resistor.

Comment: @pebbles, given that OP's schematic had no designators, that would make it more difficult to see the correspondence between the old schematic and the new one.